# ngx-bootstrap modal not detecting my component properties

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap for bootstrap 3.3.7 and currently trying to get the modal service to work completely.  The modal dialog opens, but the only content that appears is the static content.  None of the dynamic content that I'm passing to the service works, primarily because the bsModalRef doesn't seem to pick up my component property.

Here's the Modal component:

```
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CallCenter } from 'app/shared/dsg/models/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'dsg-call-centers-dialog',
  templateUrl: './call-centers-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./call-centers-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class CallCentersDialogComponent {
  public data: CallCenter[] = [];

  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) { }

}
```

Then in my host component, this is the code snippet for opening the dialog:

```
this.bsModalRef = this._modalService.show(CallCentersDialogComponent);
this.bsModalRef.content.data = this.itemData;  // Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'
```

So the dialog is opening as it should, but the data property of my dialog component isn't available.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm using 1.8.1. and doing the same thing but with the same result you have here.

Comment: @nbppp2 - no, I ended up using ng2-bootstrap-modal instead.  It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in 1.8.1 of ngx-bootstrap, try it

Comment: He said he is using version 3.3.7, so how does your answer help?

Comment: I'm talking about ngx-bootstrap, not bootstrap